# Why only the first column has values when assign values to a matrix in a nested loop?

Tags: r, matrix, nested-loops

I create a `matrix`, and I want to assign `3` to every entry of this `matrix` by a `nested for loop`.

```
   N=5    
   be<- matrix(rep(NA, 5*N), ncol = N)
    for (j in 1:5){
      for (i in 1:N) {
        be[j][i]<-3
      }}
```

The result is:

```
> be
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Also there are `20` identical `warnings` like:

```
In be[j] <- `*vtmp*` :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I expected the result being:

```
> be
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]    3   3   3   3   3
    [2,]    3   3   3   3   3
    [3,]    3   3   3   3   3
    [4,]    3   3   3   3   3
    [5,]    3   3   3   3   3
```

Why is that and how can I fix my codes?

Comment: Maybe you meant either `be[j,i]` or `be[i,j]` not `be[j][i]`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem you're actually trying to solve more complicated? Otherwise there is no need to do this in a nested for loop.

```
N=5    
be<- matrix(rep(NA, 5*N), ncol = N)
be[] <- 3
be
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3    3    3
[5,]    3    3    3    3    3
```

Comment: I need to assign values to a matrix in a nested for loop. I just symplify my question in this way.